# Display html presentation of OSMap-Sitemap into module position

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, menu-item

I created a sitemap with osmap. All works fine, I created for testing a new menuitem "Sitemap" put a refenrence to osmaps and get my sitemap on a different page.

But i want to display the Sitemap on every page. Is it possible to display **the content** of my new menu item "Sitemap" to a module position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **Wrapper module** with the URL set to `index.php?option=com_osmap&view=xml&tmpl=component&id=1` or similar and Auto Add set to `No`

Alternatively, you could use [Regular Labs Components Anywhere](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/components-anywhere) to display the HTML Sitemap in a module.